# Testing performance by catching the numbers of queries generated

Tags: performance-testing

We are using Hibernate. And Hibernate like any tools can be use badly and generate too much queries if it is used by a novice developer.

In order to prevent this, i would like to test some dao againt real production database and assert that this
test generate only N queries, no matter what tools is used (Hibernate, Ibatis) as long it is using jdbc underneath.

```
...
@MaxSqlQueries(5)
public void testPerformanceDao(){
}
```

We are using Spring test framework.
I'm wondering if anyone has implemented such thing or any framework with Junit allows that.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update !
I have proposed this feature  to the spring team test and it seems it will be implemented as it was already assigned to someone.
See [SPR-8569](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-8569)